# ZIP and DOCX Magic Number

Tags: python

I read the first byte to differentiate file types but both zip and DOCX has the same  magic number.
how can i know what zip and what docx ?
what are the diffrent?

Comment: @match: Answer to linked question *might* be a good approach, but it isn't a dup because it's the wrong language. Feel free to implement it in Python and post an answer…

Comment: @someone: You will need to use other information in the file or about it (like its extension) to tell the difference. If all else fails, assume it one or the other and `try` to do things with it but be prepared to catch any exception the get raised — a very "pythonic" way to do things.